# avoid message alert tone while listing to music

Tags: iphone, ios4, audio-player

I want to play a sound in a custom made music player in iphone , but when ever message will come , an alert sound will interrupt the currently playing sound , so is there a way to get rid of this message alert tone *(through programming)* while listening to music in iphone.

Answer (score 0):

No, because those alerts are coming from other apps.  You don't have control over the behavior of other apps' alerts via the SDK.